# Control subarray of state in form React

Tags: reactjs, forms, axios

I have a container with boxes (divs), and inside these Boxes, there are N checkboxes. The boxes and the checks are fetched from a server and listed on the screen. I need to Control the checkbox state to set a check according to other fetches. How can I do that?

**Edit:**
I did a fetch to get the box (modules). Each module has an array of checkboxes (that I call features):

```
modules = [{ 
  id,
  name,
  features: [{
    id,
    value
  }]
}]
```

I created a new state `checkModules` to control the `checked` property from the checkbox. When I do the fetchModules, I set the checkModules according to the fetched data.

```js
const PermissionsPage = () => {

 const [modules, setModules] = useState([]);
 const [checkModules, setCheckModules] = useState([]); //state to control the checkboxes 'checked' propertie

 useEffect(() => {
  api.get('/modules').then(res => {
    setModules(res.data.modules);
    setCheckModules(
     res.data.modules.map(m => ({
       id: m.id,
       features: m.features.map(f => ({ id: f.id, checked: false }))
       }))
     );
  }
 });

 const handleChange = (m,f,e) => {
  let temp = checkModules;
  //the propertie is changed, but the checkbox don't 'check'.
  temp[m].features[f].checked = !temp[m].features[f].checked;
  setCheckModules(temp);
 }

return (){
  <div>
    {modules.map((module, m) => (
      <div>
      <span>{module.name}</span>
      {module.features.map((feature, f) => (<checkbox onChange={() => handleChange(m,f)} checked={checkModules[m] !== undefined ? checkModules[m].features[f].checked : false}/>))}
      </div>
    )}
  </div>
}
}
```

I tried to reproduce the code simplifying the use of components =).

Comment: You need to show us some code related to your question.

Comment: i've updated the question with some code to explain.

Answer (score 0):

I solve it. I'll post the changes =).

```js
const PermissionsPage = () => {

 const [modules, setModules] = useState([]);
 const [checkModules, setCheckModules] = useState([]); //state to control the checkboxes 'checked' propertie

 useEffect(() => {
  api.get('/modules').then(res => {
    setModules(res.data.modules);
    setCheckModules(
     res.data.modules.map(m => ({
       id: m.id,
       name: m.name,
       features: m.features.map(f => ({ id: f.id, name: f.name, checked: false }))
       }))
     );
  }
 });

 const handleChange = (m,f,e) => {
  let temp = [...checkModules]; //that's the point. You need to take the state as a new array;
  temp[m].features[f].checked = !temp[m].features[f].checked;
  setCheckModules(temp);
 }

return (){
  <div>
    {checkModules.map((module, m) => (
      <div>
      <span>{module.name}</span>
      {checkModules[m].features.map((feature, f) => (<checkbox onChange={() => handleChange(m,f)} checked={feature.checked}/>))}
      </div>
    )}
  </div>
}
}
```